# Gradle adding compile dependencies to Proguard libraryjars

Tags: gradle, proguard

I'm trying to add compile dependencies(B.jar and C.jar) to proguard [libraryjars](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#libraryjars).

Running:

```
println configurations.compile.collect()
```

I get:

```
[../B.jar, ../C.jar]
```

Here's what I've attempted:

```
task proguard(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    ...
    libraryjars "${configurations.compile.collect()}"
    ...
}
```

For reference, the following works:

```
task proguard(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    ...
    libraryjars "../B.jar"
    libraryjars "../C.jar"
    ...
}
```

This is obviously and example and my real projects has many dependencies. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

Ah, it was as simple as:

```
libraryjars files(configurations.compile.collect())
```

Comment: Thank you, I searched hours for this

Comment: Where do you put that?

Comment: how do you add them into fatjar

Answer (score 11):

Since Gradle 3.4+ with the deprecation of "compile" in favor of "implementation" ([as described here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_compile_avoidance)) this worked:

```
libraryjars configurations.findByName('runtimeClasspath').getFiles()
```